# Ember CLI Simple Auth not found

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-simple-auth

Installed Ember Simple Auth for Ember CLI with `npm install --save-dev ember-cli-simple-auth` command. Installation was successfull. ember-cli-simple-auth got added to node_modules and an entry was inserted into package.json.

when starting the server i am getting the following error:

```
ENOENT, no such file or directory '/Users/xxx/Sites/xxxx-webclient/tmp/tree_merger-tmp_dest_dir-i7zvuTyq.tmp/ember-cli-simple-auth.js'
```

#### package.json:

```
{
  "name": "xxxx-webclient",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "directories": {
    "doc": "doc",
    "test": "test"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ember server",
    "build": "ember build",
    "test": "ember test"
  },
  "repository": "https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-cli",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 0.10.0"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.2.0",
    "broccoli-asset-rev": "0.0.17",
    "broccoli-ember-hbs-template-compiler": "^1.5.0",
    "ember-cli": "0.0.40",
    "ember-cli-autoprefixer": "0.0.3",
    "ember-cli-ember-data": "0.1.0",
    "ember-cli-ic-ajax": "0.1.1",
    "ember-cli-sass": "^1.0.1",
    "ember-cli-simple-auth": "^0.6.4-1",
    "express": "^4.1.1",
    "glob": "^3.2.9",
    "originate": "0.1.5"
  }
}
```

#### bower.json

```
{
  "name": "xxx-webclient",
  "dependencies": {
    "handlebars": "~1.3.0",
    "jquery": "^1.11.1",
    "qunit": "~1.12.0",
    "ember-qunit": "~0.1.8",
    "ember": "1.6.1",
    "ember-resolver": "~0.1.5",
    "loader": "stefanpenner/loader.js#1.0.0",
    "ember-cli-shims": "stefanpenner/ember-cli-shims#0.0.2",
    "ember-load-initializers": "stefanpenner/ember-load-initializers#0.0.2",
    "ember-qunit-notifications": "^0.0.3",
    "ember-cli-test-loader": "rjackson/ember-cli-test-loader#0.0.2",
    "griddler": "~0.0.8",
    "parsleyjs": "~2.0.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "modernizr": "~2.8.3"
  }
}
```

#### JS

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import SimpleAuth from 'ember-cli-simple-auth';
import ICAjax from 'ic-ajax';

var XXXAuthorizer = SimpleAuth.Authorizers.Base.extend({
    authorize: function(jqXHR, requestOptions) {
        //some code
    }
});

var XXXAuthenticator = SimpleAuth.Authenticators.Base.extend({
    authenticate: function(options) {
        // Some Code
    },
    restore: function(data) {
        // some code
    }
});


export default {
    name: 'authentication',
    initialize: function(container, application) {
        container.register('authenticator:xxx', XXXAuthenticator);
        container.register('authorizer:xxx', XXXAuthorizer);
        SimpleAuth.setup(container, application, {
            authorizerFactory: 'authorizer:xxx',
            routeAfterAuthentication: "dashboard"
        });
    }
};
```

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had a wrong include of `simple-auth/authenticators/base` and `simple-auth/authorizers/base`

```
import Base from simple-auth/authenticators/base
```

and

```
import Base from simple-auth/authorizers/base
```